# displaying values stored in input array in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
var lname, fname;

function _(x){
return document.getElementById(x);
}
function process(x){

lname= $('input[name=lname]').val();
fname= $('input[name=fname]').val();

_("display_lname").innerHTML=lname;
 _("display_fename").innerHTML=fname;
}
</script>


<!--html-->

<input type="text" name="fname[0]">
<input type="text" name="lname[0]">
<input type="text" name="fname[1]">
<input type="text" name="lname[1]">
<!--and so on-->



Last Name: <span id="display_lname"></span>
First Name: <span id="display_fname"></span>
```

I would want a for loop to loop through them all and display the value. i was trying to implement it but was unsuccessful. I would gladly appreciate the help.

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do? there is no `id` attribute and you are trying to get the element using `id`

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly? Do you want to display the text box inputs in the two spans??

Comment: my problem exactly i dont want to use id to get the values but i tried using name but it throws an error. Yes but i am trying to display the inputs in the two spans using a for loop because i have alot more inputs generated dynamically using jquery.

Comment: Something like https://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodkohansal/ofkv63ds/1/ ?

Comment: @Mahmood Kohansal yes but i don't want to use the number in the array how can i dynamically loop through them using a for loop

Comment: @ShannaChambers If you are talking about numbers in name attributes , `$('input[name^=X]')` selector with `each()` function doesn't check numbers. Even it's possible to use same class for inputs and select on `class` names instead of `name` attribute. like https://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodkohansal/ofkv63ds/2/

Comment: @ShannaChambers if you got correct answer, it's recommended to mark it as accepted, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need data of all inputs with same name. You can use jQuery selector `$('input[name^=X]')` to find all inputs that their name starts with `X` and `.each()` function to handle them.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="fname[0]" value="rrr"> <!-- VALUE ADDED -->
<input type="text" name="lname[0]" value="sss"> <!-- VALUE ADDED -->
<input type="text" name="fname[1]" value="ddd"> <!-- VALUE ADDED -->
<input type="text" name="lname[1]" value="eee"> <!-- VALUE ADDED -->
```

JS:

```
l_str = '';
$('input[name^=lname]').each(function() {
   l_str += $(this).val();
   l_str += ',';
});
$("#display_lname").html(l_str);

f_str = '';
$('input[name^=fname]').each(function(x) {
   f_str += $(this).val();
   f_str += ',';
});
$("#display_fname").html(f_str);
```

Result:

```
Last Name: sss,eee,
First Name: rrr,ddd,
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodkohansal/ofkv63ds/1/)

It's possible to select from `class` attribute instead of `name` attribute. you can add class to your inputs that are creating dynamically and use `$(input.CLASSNAME)` selector.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodkohansal/ofkv63ds/2/)

Comment: remember i am the one inputting the values they aren't assign statically

Comment: you must add `value` to your inputs, `name` does not appear in html. output of code in printing in front of `spans`.

Comment: i am not understanding you so how can i achieve  what i want then if i have to add value to the input statically it makes no sense then. So your telling me the user can not type any values in the input box they have to be assigned?

Comment: there is noting staticly here. if user types in input, automatically value sets for input. you don't need to set value. I set value to show the results. but if you want to get uses value you must have a button or something like that and set event handler on it's click, that user click on it and then call this code.

Comment: its simple, just use `$('select').val()`, like https://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodkohansal/ofkv63ds/4/

Answer (score 0):

Note, element having `name` attribute set to `fname` and `lname` do not appear at `html`.

You can select elements having `name` attribute value of `fname[0]`, `lname[0]`, or other attribute, by quoting `name` attribute value at attribute selector passed to `jQuery()`, e.g.,`$('input[name="fname[0]"]')`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!--html-->

<input type="text" name="fname[0]" value="abc">
<input type="text" name="lname[0]" value="123">
<input type="text" name="fname[1]">
<input type="text" name="lname[1]">
<!--and so on-->



Last Name: <span id="display_lname"></span>
First Name: <span id="display_fname"></span>
<script>
  var lname, fname;

  function _(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
  }

  function process(x) {

    lname = $('input[name="lname[0]"]').val();
    fname = $('input[name="fname[0]"]').val();
    console.log($('input[name="lname[0]"]'))
    _("display_lname").innerHTML = lname;
    _("display_fename").innerHTML = fname;
  }
  process()
</script>
```

Comment: i would like it to be dynamic not static using a for loop or something because its alot of input fields